# How to solve image upload into database

Tags: php, mysql, image-uploading

```
$target_path = "image/";
$image = basename($_FILES['photo']['name']);
$complete_path = $target_path . $image;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $complete_path);
```

There is no issue for me to upload image into database with small file size.
When the image file size is too big, it won't show you error and will still upload. But the image file was not move to my image folder.
How can I solve this issue to allow large file sizes?

Comment: error reporting/checking (PHP/MySQL) should be throwing something, that's if you're checking for them that is. Plus, in db; as what, blob? text?

Comment: php memory_limit , and upload_max_filesize i think are the issue

Comment: POST Content-Length of 11596709 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0

Comment: this is the error i get

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the memory_limit, and upload_max_filesize directives in php.ini and adjust them as needed

```
// .ex
memory_limit = 64M
upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
```

Answer (score 0):

First Try this to see result

```
<?php
echo ini_get('upload-max-filesize'),'<br />',ini_get('post-max-size'),'<br />';
?>
```

if it is not satisfy your upload file size then try to increase

```
ini_set('upload-max-filesize', '25M');
ini_set('post_max_size', '25M');
```

Comment: can you explain in detail

Comment: check http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php for more info about `post-max-size` and `upload-max-filesize`

Answer (score 0):

// try this in html page

```
<input type="file" name="file" value="<?php echo $row->timg ?>" class="" id="input01">
```

// tyr this in php page

```
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif") 
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") 
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg") 
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")) 
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 2000000)) 
  { 
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) 
    { 
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />"; 
    } 
  else 
    { 


    if (file_exists("upload/temple/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) 
      { 

      } 
    else 
      { 
              chmod("upload/temple/",0777); 
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], 
      "upload//temple/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]); 
      //copy("upload/".$FILES["file"]["name"]); 
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/temple/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]; 
      } 
    } 
  } 
else 
  { 
  echo "Invalid file"; 
  }
```